# how can i sync two Backbone fetch calls with JQuery WHEN and THEN

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

i found out a cool thing in jquery:
you can do:

```
$.when([$.get(..), $.ajax(...), $.getJSON(...)]).then(function(data1,data2,data3){
         // code to run when all requests are done
        });
```

this is great when you want to sync many ajax calls.

in backbone an ajax call is being issued every time you fetch a model or collection:

```
cardsCollection.fetch();
```

my question is how can i achieve similar syncing capabilities with backbone model/collection fetching:

i would like to do something like:

```
$.when([series.fetch(), cardsCollection.fetch()]).then(function(){
            cardsListView.seriesID = seriesID;
            cardsListView.seriesName = series.get('seriesName');
            cardsListView.template = _.template(CardsListTemplate);
            cardsListView.render();
            $('#loader').hide();
        });
```

is it possible?

tnx. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just pass several Deferred to `jQuery.when`: `$.when(series.fetch(), cardsCollection.fetch()).then(...)`

Comment: Not clear what the solution is, please provide a code sample.

Comment: @drogon, Sorry, I'm not sure what code you want to see. What do you try to achieve by using jQuery.Deferred?

Answer (score 4):

`$.when` does not accept an array, you would need to use `.apply` with `$.when`.

```
$.when.apply($,[series.fetch(), cardsCollection.fetch()]).done(dostuff);
```

However, `series.fetch()` and `cardsCollection.fetch()` would have to return deferred objects.

If you don't use `.apply`, it will resolve instantly because you didn't give it a deferred object.